# WSO2 API Manager - Sharing registry

Tags: wso2

I'm following this documentation set:
http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2010/04/sharing-registry-space-across-multiple-product-instances/#CO_JDBC

I currently have 3 DBs: User, Registry, and API per the API Manager documentation.
I have things configured as noted with the exception of having a cluster.

```
    <!--for store and publisher only-->
    <dbConfig name="govregistry">
        <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2REG_DB</dataSource>
    </dbConfig>
    <remoteInstance url="https://localhost:9447/registry">
        <id>gov</id>
        <dbConfig>govregistry</dbConfig>
        <readOnly>false</readOnly>
        <enableCache>true</enableCache>
        <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
    </remoteInstance>
    <mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
        <instanceId>gov</instanceId>
        <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
    </mount>
```

I have one server for store (on port 9447), and publisher (on port 9446) as well as a different server for gateway (port 9445), and key manager (port 9444) but continually get the following when starting the store or publisher (the WSO2 doc for API Manager:http://docs.wso2.org/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+API+Manager
 did NOT say I should create entries for those items in the regsitry.xml file).

TID: [0] [AM] [2014-01-22 17:26:30,409] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.util.GovernanceUtils} -  Error in getting the path from the registry. Execute query failed with message : PooledConnection has already been closed. {org.wso2.carbon.governance.api.util.GovernanceUtils}

Should I have created a whole new seperate DB instance for the shared config/governance, or should I be reusing the existing Registry DB?  Stabbing in the dark as to why the connection pool is already closed...

Comment: Noted that the following doc: http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance460/Remote+Instance+and+Mount+Configuration+Details says that the DBconfig should not be the default config.  In my case, when following WSo2 API Manager documentation the carbon DB config points to the REG_DB, and then we make another entry that points to REG_DB.  That would seem to indicate that I should have a REG_DB and another Shared_REG_DB...but the documentation is not clear on if it means 2 different DB's or just different DBConfigs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to share your gov and config registry among the instances of the API Manager. Add a new entry in the Registry.xml for this. I recommend you to use a standalone DB to mount the gov and config registry.

Comment: So I should have my existing REG_DB and then a new SHARED_REG_DB for the registry.xml governance settings?

Comment: I also note that the doc: http://docs.wso2.org/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+API+Manager only says that I should be using the REG_DB.  Although, it seems like the config only has the publisher and store share the goverance mount.  should the Key Manager and Gateway components also share the same governance mount?

Comment: I've configured the publisher and store instances to use a sharedREG_DB. However, any references to the Carbon datastore for those will go to REG_DB. In addition my KeyManager and Gateway instances are both pointing to REG_DB. That doesn't make sense to me...shouldn't they ALL point to sharedREG_DB? Further...shouldn't all references go to the sharedREG_DB, including CarbonDB?  However, if I do that, I'm back to the original situation of everything pointing to 1 registry DB and getting connection pool errors.

Answer (score 0):

have the local space pointing to the local registry(H2 DB), mount the config and gov space on a remote mysql DB which is shared by other instances on the deployment.